# pg_restore command is not accepting filename as variable

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, pg-restore

```
$latest = 'filename.sql'  
kubectl exec -n testnamspace pod/test-- sh -c 'PGPASSWORD=ss pg_restore --clean -h postgresql -p 5432 -U test_user -d dbName -F c /tmp/$latest'
```

This is the error I am getting while reading dbName file:

> pg_restore: error: could not open input file "$/tmp/": No such file or
> directory

When I try to echo $latest, it is working but not with pg_restore command. Any help in this regard would be appreciated

Comment: Bash does not do variable interpolation in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using double `quotes`

```
kubectl exec -n testnamspace pod/test -- sh -c "PGPASSWORD=ss pg_restore --clean -h postgresql -p 5432 -U test_user -d dbName -F c /tmp/$latest"
```

or

```
latest='filename.sql'
command="PGPASSWORD=ss pg_restore --clean -h postgresql -p 5432 -U test_user -d dbName -F c /tmp/$latest"
kubectl exec -n testnamspace pod/test -- sh -c "$command"
```